# Instances of a class and its sub-class sharing state in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, state

How to make one instance of a derived class share attributes and state with another instance of its base class in Python?

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.value = a

    def method1(self):
        self.value += 1
        return self.value

class Foo_child(Foo):
    def __init__(self, Foo_instance, c, d):
        super().__init__()

A = Foo(30,40)
B = Foo_child(A,50,60)
```

What i need is some way where changing `B` should affect `A` and vice versa.

For e.g. If i call `B.method1`, then i need `A` to have a `A.value` of 31 and vice versa. Is there any obvious pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? `return self.value+=1` is not going to work well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a containment (*has-a*) relationship, not a *is-a* relationship. It may *also* be necessary to make `Foo_child` inherit from `Foo` (they provide the same functionality), but in essence you want to delegate handling of `value` and `method1` to `Foo_instance`.

Re-implement `method1` on `Foo_child` to delegate to `Foo_instance`, `value` on `Foo_child` should be a `property` object that also delegates:

```
class Foo_child(Foo):
    def __init__(self, Foo_instance, c, d):
        super().__init__(c, d)
        self.Foo_instance = Foo_instance

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.Foo_instance.value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self.Foo_instance.value = value

    def method1(self):
        return self.Foo_instance.method1()
```